# What does the "C" used as an offset in assembly mean?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, reversing

I have the following piece of code:

```
RtlGetElementGenericTable:
7C9624E0 PUSH EBP
7C9624E1 MOV EBP,ESP
7C9624E3 MOV ECX,DWORD PTR [EBP+8]
7C9624E6 MOV EDX,DWORD PTR [ECX+14]
7C9624E9 MOV EAX,DWORD PTR [ECX+C]
```

And I was wondering what does the "C" in  `MOV EAX,DWORD PTR [ECX+C]` means.
Is a variable? Is it a register? Is it something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `C` in `MOV EAX,DWORD PTR [ECX+C]` is hexadecimal C (decimal 12).

And note that `8` in  `MOV ECX,DWORD PTR [EBP+8]` and `14` in `MOV EDX,DWORD PTR [ECX+14]` are also hexadecimal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably an hexadecimal value. So it means 12.